# Unable to create a new Android Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I am working on Eclipse with ADT 22.3.0; I cannot create a new Android Activity. Generally we select the project, right click and go to New->Other->Android->Android Activity to create an activity.java file. I do the same. But after giving name and etc and clicking "Finish", nothing happens. No Activity.java file is generated under the "src" folder.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information given the only things I can suggest is:

1. Restart Eclipse, try again.
2. Restart your computer, try again.
3. Reinstall Eclipse, try again.
4. Reinstall your computer (including Eclipse), try again.

After that I'm sure it works :) Eclipse behaves... odd from time to time. I find Android Studio (IntellIJ) to be much better, check it out at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html.